# how to use more than one "cart library" in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to use more than one "cart library" in codeigniter. I want to make a cart library for selling items and another for purchase items what should I do??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to duplicate the cart library.

Rename the php file and class name of the duplicate (to say `Cart_selling`) and put it in the `application/libraries` folder. Then do a find and replace for `cart_contents` in the duplicate to `cart_contents_selling`.

Then you can use:

`$this->load->library('cart'); $this->cart->whatever` for purchases (so this is the native CI class)

and

`$this->load->library('cart_selling'); $this->cart_selling->whatever` for items that are being sold

---

Addendum: I'm not sure why you want to do this. Why would items someone is selling go in their cart? Makes little sense.